# cakephp how do you create a model with only foreign keys?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table with two foreign keys: `account_id`, `buyer_id`, `comment`

How can I create a model for the table `account_buyers`?

Is it standard cakephp practice to create a model for primary key-less tables?

I want to be able to use cakephp's ORM to update files and select data. Is this just too impractical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a normal example of [HasManyThrough [see more details in the CakePHP book]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

But - you'll still want to have an id field, whether you want to use it or not.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem...I dont need an id field.

Comment: I realize you don't "need" one, but for CakePHP purposes you should have it. All you have to do is add the field and forget it even exists.